# Translate raw query into Query Builder in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO users_access_dynamic_views (dynamic_view_id, user_id, ordinal_ranking) 
SELECT ?, u.user_id, COUNT(uav.id) + 1 from users_access_dynamic_views uav
  RIGHT JOIN users_in_circles u ON uav.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.circle_id = ?
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

The first `?` should be replaced by a PHP variable like `$viewId` and the second by `$circleId`.

How do I use the [Query Builder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html) to create this? Do I need to use subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would use a subquery for the `SELECT` part, and pass it into `Query::values()`, something like:

```php
$values = $connection
    ->newQuery()
    ->select([':viewId', 'u.user_id', 'COUNT(uav.id) + 1'])
    ->from(['uav' => 'users_access_dynamic_views'])
    ->rightJoin(['u' => 'users_in_circles'], ['uav.user_id = u.user_id'])
    ->where(['u.circle_id' => $circleId])
    ->group('u.user_id');

$query = $connection
    ->newQuery()
    ->insert(['dynamic_view_id', 'user_id', 'ordinal_ranking'])
    ->into('users_access_dynamic_views')
    ->values($values);

$query->bind(':viewId', $viewId, 'type');
```

Note the [**explicit binding**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#binding-values) for the input in `select()`, [**you don't get automatic binding**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions) here as in `where()`, so you have to keep this safe yourself. It's necessary to use `bind()` on the outer query (`$query`), as the bindings of the subquery are being ditched (not sure if this is a bug).

Resulting SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO
    users_access_dynamic_views (dynamic_view_id, user_id, ordinal_ranking)
SELECT
    :viewId, u.user_id, COUNT(uav.id) + 1
FROM
    users_access_dynamic_views uav
RIGHT JOIN
    users_in_circles u ON uav.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE
    u.circle_id = :c0
GROUP BY
    u.user_id
```

In case the value `$viewId` is something simple like a numeric value, you could of course simply cast it directly instead of using bindings:

```php
    ->select([(int)$viewId, 'u.user_id', 'COUNT(uav.id) + 1'])
```

Comment: I got thrown off by the bind statement. Could you use bind in the first code block instead of the casting?

Comment: @KimStacks Restructured my answer.

Comment: @KimStacks You're welcome, note that I've fixed a small mistake with the join conditions, this should not have been in `key => value` format as the value is not supposed to be escaped.

Comment: your query worked beautifully for me. Thank you. Since the new ORM, I have been trying to avoid writing raw query. Very happy I succeed with your help.